# Security risk in setting PHP file permissions to full

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm running XAMPP on Ubuntu, and I copied the lampp folder to /opt/. I also downloaded CodeIgniter to htdocs/, and created and modified some files in it, including changing their permissions. Are there files in CodeIgniter that I shouldn't set permission to full, because maybe then once I upload them onto a server anyone can see their contents?

Comment: Not necessarily, but give full access to cache and images folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, your CodeIgniter should be setup such that the `application` and `system` folder lie outside your document root. Only the `index.php` file along with any assets (images, javascript, css etc.) should lie within the document root.

As for file permissions, `755` works fine. There's no need for full permissions `777`.